# Android 14 Non-SDK Interface Restriction

Tags: android, android-14

I am looking forward to the Android 14 synchronization with my app. I have been analyzed to my app's APK with veridex and then, one interface will be blocked with Android 14 and above. I checked my source codes but I don't use these interfaces. And I don't understand how can I handle this situation. I am sharing the NON-sdk report section. Anybody is encountered that? Or can anybody help me about this topic?

```
Reflection blocked Landroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;->rebase use(s):
       Landroidx/core/content/res/ResourcesCompat$ThemeCompat$Api23Impl;->rebase(Landroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)V



164 hidden API(s) used: 80 linked against, 84 through reflection
    142 in unsupported
    1 in blocked
    7 in max-target-o
    11 in max-target-p
    3 in max-target-q
    0 in max-target-r
```

I don't add the full report to my question because report file have a lot of unsupported reflections.

I tried to change "Resource.Theme" usages. But after changes report doesn't change.